# Temperature sensor utilization to a LED on

Tags: arduino-uno

I work on a program which should light a LED on when the temperature is below 30°C. I am getting an error while compiling it. Could you guys please look into it? What am I doing wrong?

```
/*
 * Code d'exemple pour le capteur LM35DZ (0°C ~ +110°C).
 */
const int led_rouge = 3; //définition de la broche 3 de la carte étant la LED

 int valeur_brute;
// Fonction setup(), appelée au démarrage de la carte Arduino
void setup() {

  // Initialise la communication avec le PC
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //initialisation de la broche 3 comme étant une sortie 
  pinMode(led_rouge, OUTPUT);


}

// Fonction loop(), appelée continuellement en boucle tant que la carte Arduino est alimentée
void loop() {

  // Mesure la tension sur la broche A1
  int valeur_brute = analogRead(A1);

  // Transforme la mesure (nombre entier) en température via un produit en croix
  float temperature_celcius = valeur_brute * (5.0 / 1023.0 * 100.0);

  // Envoi la mesure au PC pour affichage et attends 250ms
  Serial.println(temperature_celcius);
  delay(250);

  //Condition de fonctionnement de la LED
  if( valeur_brute < 100/110 ) //si température inférieur à 30°C
  {
    digitalWrite(led_rouge, HIGH);
  }
  if ( valeur_brute > 100/110 ){
    digitalWrite(led_rouge, LOW);
  }
}
```

This is the error I get with the previous code

```
F:\Alexis\Temperature\Temperature - LED.ino: In function 'void setup()':
F:\Alexis\Temperature\Temperature - LED.ino:6:6: error: redefinition of 'void setup()'
 void setup() {
      ^
F:\Alexis\Temperature\Temperature.ino:8:6: note: 'void setup()' previously defined here
 void setup() {
      ^
F:\Alexis\Temperature\Temperature - LED.ino: In function 'void loop()':
F:\Alexis\Temperature\Temperature - LED.ino:13:6: error: redefinition of 'void loop()'
 void loop() {
      ^
F:\Alexis\Temperature\Temperature.ino:20:6: note: 'void loop()' previously defined here
 void loop() {
      ^
exit status 1
Erreur de compilation pour la carte Arduino/Genuino Uno
```

Comment: Not sure about your actual error but don't terminate your `if(condition)` with a `;`.

Comment: I resolved that, thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple sketches open at the same time (.ino files)?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: The error tells you that its trying to compile two sketches: `Temperature - LED.ino` and `Temperature.ino`. Could you double-check?

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining a CONST variable in your setup 
`int led_rouge = LOW;`.
A const variable cannot be overwritten. Just delete the line in the setup. The following Sketch is working fine for me:

```
const int led_rouge = 3; 
int valeur_brute;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led_rouge, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int valeur_brute = analogRead(A1);
  float temperature_celcius = valeur_brute * (5.0 / 1023.0 * 100.0);
  Serial.println(temperature_celcius);
  delay(250);
  if( temperature_celcius < 100/110 ){
    digitalWrite(led_rouge, HIGH);
  }
  if ( temperature_celcius > 100/110 ){
    digitalWrite(led_rouge, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: @AlexisLEROUX edit your post with the new code pls, so we can provide a better answer

Comment: @AlexisLEROUX
Use my code in a new .ino file in a NEW FOLDER. Just the .ino file in there, should work! :)